# Disorganized disks because of different disk technologies - LVM an answer?

Tags: lvm, ssd

I have a 1 TB spinning HD, and a 256 GB SSD.

I keep my OS and large projects on the SSD, for speed.

The rest is on the spinning HD, because of its size.

The problem:  This means I have things to back up spread out over different devices.  Instead, I'd like to be organized and have everything I need to back up ("my" stuff) under, say, /data.  Like the old days, when we used different partitions for different uses.

Symlinks aren't the answer because either a) I end up with backed up symlinks rather than the data, or b) I dereference them, meaning if I ever restore I end up with everything in one pile (and it dereferences other symlinks lower in the hierarchy, making copies).

Can LVM be intelligently used here to somehow create a volume for the OS and a volume for my data, but split PV's between them?